# Converting Markdown to PDF in Pandoc causes tables to cross margins

Tags: markdown, pandoc

What command should I be typing to make tables display within margins instead of crossing over?

[image: Crossing the Margin]

I used:

```
pandoc --variable papersize=a5paper -s VF_Rules.md -o VF_Rules.pdf
```

(I tried to just use this template, but I couldn't get it apply without an error. https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template)